# MySQL Query running slow when using REPLACE function instead of CASE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it better to use **CASE statements** instead of **REPLACE functions** in MySQL when mapping a comma-separated-string field?

The below query runs extremely slow using replace.
Note, the underlying `user_roles` table is of format [user_id (bigint), string_of_user_role_ids (varchar(200))]

```
-- this runs slowly
select      string_of_user_role_ids
            , replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(string_of_user_role_ids, '10', 'Scientist'), '9', 'Superhero'), '8', 'Teacher'), '7', 'Journalist'), '6', 'Farmer')
            , count(1) 
from        user_roles
group by    1,2 
order by    3 desc
```

```
-- this runs quickly, but is more difficult to keep adding in multiple new when clauses whenever a new user role is added
select      string_of_user_role_ids
            , case  when string_of_user_role_ids= "6" then 'Farmer'
                    when string_of_user_role_ids= "7" then 'Journalist'
                    when string_of_user_role_ids= "8" then 'Teacher'    
                    when string_of_user_role_ids= "6,7" then 'Farmer, Journalist'
                    when string_of_user_role_ids= "6,8" then 'Farmer, Teacher'
                    when string_of_user_role_ids= "7,8" then 'Journalist, Teacher'
                    when string_of_user_role_ids= "6,7,8" then 'Farmer, Journalist, Teacher'    
                    -- ... etc.
                    else 'Unknown' end as app_user_type
            , count(1) 
from        user_roles  
group by    1,2 
order by    3 desc
```

Ideally I would use the **replace** function instead of a **case statement**, as it seems easier to scale out in terms of expanding the code and less risk to manage.

I can't understand why one query runs quickly and the other very slowly (seconds versus minutes, after a few mins I killed the slow query).
Ideas/questions are welcome please.

Overall objective is to re-use this code snippet to create a data model which enables users to do descriptive analysis based on various user segments.

Comment: Please explain the logic you are trying to implement.  Also, don't store multiple values in a single column.  That is just evidence of a bad data model.

Comment: Is this a subquery of a much larger query and this is the piece you have narrowed down to being the bottleneck or is it this query itself that is slow? Also about how many rows are you trying to process?

Comment: Agreed @GordonLinoff, we've inherited this unfortunately. Re-modelling at this stage is a no go. I'm left to figure it out at the BI end how to provide users a data model which enables them to to explore how the activity of the various user segments. E.g. If someone is both a Superhero and a Farmer how active is this cohort and are they more likely to do event X

Comment: @Kupokev it is about 3 million rows of data. It is just a query by itself at the moment as I look to test the logic of implementing this as a sub-query within a larger query. At the moment there are 5 different user properties, so 31 possible combinations, although I can see more being added slowly over the months.

Comment: Why do you use both DISTINCT and GROUP BY? One of them is enough. Do you get any performance improvement with only one of them?

Comment: `case` _expression_, not statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given I can't modify the schema of the database (currently) and I need to focus on query optimisation I'm list this simple suggestion from @NikitaSerbskiy posted elsewhere

"it would work faster if you would use replace/case after group by"

Answer (score 2):

REPLACE has to scan the string looking for what it needs to replace. On top of that you are doing several nested within each other. It potentially could cause some performance issues with that many rows. I have not seen it cause a major speed degradation, but I suppose it is possible. With your CASE statement it is just doing a straight string compare so it is .

If you are looking to create a data model, the way your table is set up is not ideal at all. In order to model this to do proper analysis on it, that field should be split up into a separate table of one to many relationship to properly be able to relate the data. Instead of replacing data in the string, you might look at creating a separate table and populating it by splitting the string on comma in the field string_of_user_role_ids and then do an UNPIVOT to create the multiple records. Be sure to store the user_id on the rows as well. Also, I would convert those numbers to an int column for faster joins. At that point you could throw in an index for better query performance. It may affect writes to the table, but if you are going to be doing large queries, it is worth the speed cost.

If you create this table first or build a temp table doing this, it should help with the much larger queries. Especially any of them where you need to examine these particular data points as they will be split out and you will not have to constantly be scanning through strings for comparison sakes.

I hope that gives you some ideas to explore.

Comment: I've ended up going with this approach and creating a staging table to do it in steps, thanks

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help.